# MySQL - LEFT JOIN most recent record based on datetime column

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to LEFT JOIN the most recent related record, based on a DATETIME column in the related table.

The most recent record is not the most recent one inserted; the date column is updated regularly, and it is that upon which I want to join.

I was not able to do it using a sub query in the join because the `job_id` returned does not correspond to the most recent `submitted` date.

```
SELECT o.id, j.submitted, j.id AS job_id
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id, order_id, MAX(submitted) AS submitted
    FROM jobs
    GROUP BY order_id
) j ON j.order_id = o.id
```

I also tried with a subquery in the WHERE clause, but this filters the result so that only `orders` with a `job` are returned. I need `orders` with no `jobs` as part of the result set.

```
SELECT o.id, j.submitted, j.id AS job_id
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN jobs j ON j.order_id = o.id
WHERE j.submitted = (
    SELECT MIN(submitted)
    FROM jobs
    WHERE order_id = o.id
)
```

Comment: show us sample data and expected results

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT o.id, j.submitted, j.id AS job_id
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN jobs j ON j.order_id = o.id
WHERE j.submitted = (
    SELECT MAX(submitted) FROM jobs
)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT o.id, max(j.submitted), j.id AS job_id
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN jobs j on (j.order_id = o.id)
GROUP BY o.id, j.id
ORDER BY o.id
```

The query would output each of the orders and its most recent job. If its got no job related, then the submittted and job columns are blanked.

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
    SELECT 
    o.id AS orderId, recentOrderInner.*
FROM
    orders o
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        j.order_id, j.submitted AS recent_order
    FROM
        job j
    LEFT JOIN job j_l ON (j.order_id = j_l.order_id
        AND j.submitted < j_l.submitted)
    WHERE
        j_l.submitted IS NULL
    ORDER BY aul.created DESC) AS recentOrderInner ON o.id = recentOrderInner.order_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this would use two joins, not one:

```
select . . . 
from orders o left join
     jobs j
     on o.id = j.order_id left join
     (select j2.order_id, max(j2.submitted) as max_submitted
      from jobs j2
      group by j2.order_id
     ) j2
     on j2.order_id = j.order_id and j2.max_submitted = j.max_submitted;
```

Comment: What will happen in this case when there’s two jobs with the same order and submitted date?

Comment: You would get both in the result set.